# Uploading File to Site's Server: Session Times Out

Tags: php, html, apache

Good morning everyone!

**What is happening:**
I currently have a website in which I allow users to upload files. They "pick" the location of where on the server the files get saved through choices they make.  The directory they end up picking is stored as a session variable. Once they click the upload button then the file is put to that directory. So far, no problem.  Initially I had problems with large files because of the settings in Apache. I changed the following:

Upload_max_filesize = 2M **=>** Upload_max_filesize = 0

memory_limit = 512M **=>** memory_limit = -1

This is meant to allow the user to upload any file size. This works fine for files of 400MB or so no problem.  When I tested a 16GB file however is where the problem is.  I believe from my understanding that Apache is no longer limiting the upload by size and that changing the above settings must have helped otherwise my 400 MB file wouldn't work.

**Problem:**

After the upload progress bar finishes, the page displays an error message that I have put in place if the directory location, saved in the session variable, is missing. Therefore I believe that the session may be timing out and "forgetting" the session variable. After the upload progress, which takes roughly an hour, is when the message is displayed.

**What I have tried**

After doing some research I have tried changing the following, just to see if it made a difference even:

session.gc_maxlifetime = 36000

36000 should = 10 hours. I would not keep it here eventually but just did it for testing. Even changing this still results in what I believe is timing out. I was hoping someone had suggestions, and maybe other settings, that should be changed too?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `memory_limit = 512M => memory_limit = -1` This is not needed and is generally a bad idea.

Comment: Are there any logs from your webserver / php to help narrow down the problem? At this point you're just assuming the session is timing out. Is there enough space on the partition to store the file? (Note that files get uploaded to where the TMPDIR environment variable points)

Answer (score 0):

```
$seconds = 60*60*24
set_time_limit ( int $seconds )
```

I don't know the answer exactly but i am suggesting that may be your max script running time is limited perhaps..try the above code along with your session time variable...good luck..please some one up vote me so i can post my own question.Those who edit my answer please visit my profile and see what happened to me

Comment: I tried this as well but no result. It still times out the session.

Answer (score 0):

Your PHP file may be timing out. This value is by default low. (approx 2 min.)

try this:

```
ini_set('max_execution_time', 3600); //3600 seconds = 1 hour, or value 0 for unlimited
```

Try changing this value to something higher, since those filesizes you describe probably take longer then 5 minutes to upload.

Comment: I tried this. I will let you know the results shortly.

Comment: Same result after changing the max_execution_time to = 7200 (2 hours)